# bash more effective use of sed / awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am looking for a more efficient to use the following string to get the desired result as a one liner

```
date -d @1381219358 | sed 's/\ \ /\ /g' | sed 's/[:\ ]/-/g' | sed 's/2013/13/' | awk -F '-' '{print $4"-"$5"-"$6"-"$2"-"$3"-"$8}'
```

The desired result output is as follows:

```
04-02-38-Oct-8-13
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you just trying to reformat the time? If so you can just use the date command with a format string.

Comment: Pandubear, I was just trying to reformat it. I am still learning bash / linux scripting type stuff. So I am still naive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need `sed` or `awk` for this.  You can format the output using `date`.

Try saying:

```
date -d @1381219358 +%H-%M-%S-%b-%d-%y
```

Answer (score 4):

You can format the output directly, like this:

```
date -d @1381219358 +"%H-%M-%S-%b-%d-%y"
10-02-38-Oct-08-13
```

Comment: It was just to show how it could be done, change to correct format.

Comment: Jotne, Thanks for the clarification on that